# Rails: added a new method in Rails but cant get the output on the browser window- Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I have a class 'listings_controller'. I added a method 'list' in there as follows:

```
def index     
    @listings = Listing.order(:name)  
end  


def list  
    render :text=>(@listings).to_json  
end
```

Here is my routes.rb file

root to: 'listings#index', as: 'listings'
   resources :listings do
        collection do
            get :around
        end
    end

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

When I type this into my browser:

http://localhost:3000/listings/list

I hope to see the JSON object and its contents in the browser. However, thats not happening. I was wondering if someone could assist me in diagnosing what Im doing wrong.

The webrick server says the following:

```
Started GET "/listings/list" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-18 11:56:25 -0700  
Processing by ListingsController#show as HTML  
Parameters: {"id"=>"list"}  
Listing Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "list"]]  
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
```

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Listing with id=list):
  app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:104:in `show'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following in your routes.rb:

`match 'listings/list' => 'listings#list'`

Or the shorthand:

`get 'listings/list'`

At the moment it is being routed to the show method.

Comment: This is a prime example of why *not* to use the catchall route at the bottom.